# How to convert array of subdocuments into array of primary data values returned from a $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

The `$lookup` stage will return an array of subdocuments. But the only value that I am interested in from the result of the `$lookup` is the the `_id` value. So instead of an array of `{ _id: ObjectId() }`, how do I flatten this array into just an array of ObjectId: `[ ObjectId(), Objectid(), ... ]`

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

```js
db={
  "orders": [
    {
      key: 1,
      
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      
    }
  ],
  "inventory": [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "a"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "b"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "c"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "d"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Aggregation :**

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "inventory",
      "localField": "key",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      result: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$result"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "result": {
        "$push": "$result.id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Output : returns ID in array (we can have mongodb objectId) but i have used simple numeric ID**

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "result": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Using `$unwind` and `$group` is not acceptable. The idea is to be able to transformed the array inside of the `$lookup` stage

Comment: ok got it let me update my code

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: Using your input and output as example, that's basically what I am trying to do. The `results`  array should be `[1, 2, 3]`. However, `$lookup` will return an array of subdocuments

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map the array of subdocuments, using `$map`, like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "inventory",
      "localField": "key",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "result": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$result",
          "as": "item",
          "in": "$$item._id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bf7boOmpsdY)

Comment: This works, but then this `$map` would have to be done for each document in the local collection. `$lookup` will actually be a static lookup, not dynamic, which means that mongo only needs to run it once. But the `$addFields` will be run for each document.

Comment: `$lookup` also gets triggered for every document. @BearBileFarmingIsTorture

Comment: But it's a static `$lookup`, which means it returns the same array for every document. I have manually tested. It is much faster than a dynamic `$lookup`. If it is also run for every document, then why is it so much faster?

Comment: It doesn't return the same array for each document, until and unless your data is structured that way, Also, the speed of the lookup depends upon the operations we perform, pipeline-based lookups, will be fast if we perform the comparison on indexed fields and keep the work minimal. Non-pipeline based lookups usually join on `_id` of collections, which is already indexed, that's why they are faster. @BearBileFarmingisTorture

Comment: static means that I am joining by the same value for each document. Dynamic means that I am joining by a different value for each document. And so, why do you say that a static $lookup will not return the same array for each document?

Comment: By this definition of static, the query optimizer will cache the output of the static lookup, which can't be done for dynamic lookup, that's why dynamic will be slower than the static one,

Comment: Then, going back to the original problem. Requiring the `$map` stage will mean that the `$map` must be run for each document, which is what I am trying to avoid if possible

Comment: You can avoid it using dynamic lookups, depending on how dynamic lookups vs $map performs, you can take the call.